# Edit DNS records from the command line in Mountain Lion Server

Tags: domain-name-system, command-line-interface, mac-osx-server

I'm trying to edit a DNS A record in Mountain Lion server using the serveradmin command. I can pull up the list of records using

```
sudo serveradmin settings dns
```

and I get this record I want to change:

`dns:views:_array_id:com.apple.ServerAdmin.DNS.public:primaryZones:_array_id:mysite.org:machines:_array_index:17:name = "websiteyoyo.mysite.org."
dns:views:_array_id:com.apple.ServerAdmin.DNS.public:primaryZones:mysite.org:machines:_array_index:17:ipAddresses:_array_index:0:ipAddress = "75.101.163.44"`

I use this to try to save a change:

```
sudo serveradmin settings dns:views:_array_id:com.apple.ServerAdmin.DNS.public:primaryZones:_array_id:mysite.org:machines:_array_index:17:name = "website.mysite.org."
```

This returns the error:

```
Invalid index "17", must specifiy array elements in order
```

Eventually, what I want to do is replace "website" with "@" so that I can have a naked domain redirect to my site on Heroku. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar problem in mavericks and the output of the serveradmin tool when setting a new IP is :dns:views:_array_id:com.apple.ServerAdmin.DNS.public:primaryZones:_array_id:xenji.net:machines = _empty_array

Comment: I've found this article, but it did not help me. Maybe it helps you https://discussions.apple.com/thread/130206. The discussion is a bit older, the actual manpage reflects the newer naming scheme of the array_id stuff: http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/serveradmin/